# How to check if response is an array

Tags: karate

I tried this, no luck :(

- def mySchool = {"school":"01","student":[{"name":"sam","age":35},{"name":"any","age":34}]}
- def student= mySchool.school
- print typeof student

Answer (score 2):

I would write:

```
Given def mySchool = {"school":"01","student":[{"name":"sam","age":35},{"name":"any","age":34}]}
Then match mySchool contains { student: '#array' }
# or: 
Then match mySchool == { school: '#string', student: '#array' }
```

Please check the docs at https://github.com/intuit/karate. There are many excellent examples.

Comment: I am trying to see 'student' is an array